# Does GoLang use reserved filenames?

Tags: go

In a CI/CD pipeline, we have a Go script that does some preprocessing prior to actually building our deliverable artifacts.  If I name the script main.go is that a foul in the GoLang world or is that OK?  I do not understand if there are any namespace concerns that tie back to the actual filename of the script.

I know that main.go being the script, main_test.go is the Unit Tests so I am leary and looking for guidance.

For example, if I execute from the shell (MacOS bash) the following: go test
This executes the unit tests for the main.go script which leads me to believe that main is some sort of reserved file name.  I could easily be wrong though.

Thoughts?

Comment: You do not have a go "script".  You have go source code that can be compiled into an executable.  There is no other way to run Go.  I know it's a semantic point but you'd be surprised how much confusion there is around that.

Comment: Very good point.  The answer below is sufficient!!!  Thanks for the chime in @Daniel Farrel...  Happy Hollidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename `main.go` is not special.

Go detects that a file is part of a test because it ends in `_test.go`, and detects that a package is a binary (instead of a library) because the package name is `main` (in other words, it starts with `package main`). You can use a file named `main.go` in a library.

You can see in the source code for `go/build` what `go build` looks for in files. It only has a check for the `_test` suffix, here:

https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.3:src/go/build/build.go;l=895;drc=deb3403ff52b8833df6c4e2f82cbdddeb13573dd

```
isTest := strings.HasSuffix(name, "_test.go")
```

Comment: So in other words, @kennethCrismon,  the special naming convention in this case is the suffix `_test.go`.  the name of the test doesn't have to match the name of any other file.

Comment: Perfect.  Very helpful.